# Inconsistent behaviour of bdist vs sdist when distributing a Python package

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I have a big project with the following structure. **utilities** is a collections of small modules that are reused in various places by the different components of the **big_project**, **project1**, 2, etc.

```
big_project/
|-- __init__.py
|-- utilities/        
    |-- mod1.py
    |-- mod2.py
|-- project1/
    |-- setup.py
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- src/
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- mod1.py
        |-- mod2.py
    |-- examples/
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- mod.py
|-- project2/
   |-- ...
|-- project3/
   |-- ...
```

I want to distribute **project1**, including **utilities** (because I don't want to distribute **utilities** separately). The distributed package would have the following structures:

```
project1/
    |-- utilities/
    |-- src/
    |-- examples/
```

and `project1/setup.py` looks like this:

```
setup(
    name = 'project1',
    packages = ['project1.utilities', 'project1.src', 'project1.examples'],
    package_dir = {'project1.utilities': '../utilities/',
                   'project1.src': 'src',
                   'project1.examples': 'examples'}
     )
```

The problem: `python setup.py bdist` produces a distribution with the right structure, but `python setup.py sdist` doesn't:

**bdist**: content of `project1-0.1.linux-x86_64.tar.gz`:

```
    /./usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
        |-- project1/
            |-- utilities
            |-- src
            |-- examples
```

**sdist**: `content of project1-0.1.tar.gz`:

```
    project1/
        |-- src/
        |-- examples/
```

So sdist left out the utilities module, whereas bdist included it at the correct location. Why?

If anyone wants to look at the real project: https://testpypi.python.org/pypi/microscopy where both the bsdist and sdist archives are available.

Both setuptools and distutils produce the same result. Because the project is pure Python, I'd rather use sdist...

Comment: I found a couple of related issues:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34472075/how-to-place-a-common-code-for-different-projects

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33611363/python-distutils-setup-py-does-not-move-source-to-appropriate-folder

Comment: I've hit this s**t right now. It looks like sdist command treates relative paths in setup.py literally. If you look at the console log of setyp.py sdist, you'll see that your subdirs referred via .. are copied into build/.. !!! so they are not included into the final tar or zip. Amazing. Should we file a bug?

Answer (score 0):

One way that seems to work is to use **bdist_wheel**, which despite its name produces a platform-agnostic source distribution when the content is pure Python. And wheels are suppose to be the new standard.

`setup.py` also needs to be told about the root package `project1`, otherwise `project1.__init__.py` is missing:

```
setup(
      name = 'project1',
      packages = ['project1'
                  'project1.utilities',
                  'project1.src',
                  'project1.examples'],
      package_dir = {'project1': '.',
                     'project1.utilities': '../utilities/',
                     'project1.src': 'src',
                     'project1.examples': 'examples'}
 )
```

and then

```
 python2.7 setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to update your MANIFEST.in file to include utilities folder 
e.g. *recursive-include ../utilities **